# How to get CGRect that exactly represents the views bounds and transformation?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

How can I get the transformed rect of an UIView, including translations and scaling made in the .transform property? I tried to do it this way:

```
CGRect transformed = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(theview.frame, theview.transform);
```

Doesn't work!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use UIView bounds property for that, i.e.

```
CGRect trans_rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(view.bounds, view.transform);
```